# onFormSubmit trigger sending last row submission for simultaneous submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, eventtrigger

Still very new to Google App script but managed to set up a form that populates a spreadsheet and then sends out an email with a pdf attachment with a report based on the users' data. My issue is that on simultaneous submission. The form attachment is emailed to the last respondent the number of times equal to the number of simultaneous submissions. Luckily based on the last respondent's information

I have tried `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` as well as `LockService.getScriptLock()` but did not get the problem resolved (possibly due to incorrect use). I include herewith the code I have.

Herewith the updated code

```js
//automatically send email with cash flow attached when form is submitted

function onFormSubmit(e) {
// change onFormSubmit() to onFormSubmit(e) when based on event otherwise just onFormSubmit()    

  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");
  var responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1") ;
  
  var data = e.range.getValues();
  
  //var replied = data.offset(0, e.range.getNumColumns(),0,0);
  
  //Logger.log(data)
  
  //change to data = e.range when based on event alternatively responseSheet.getRange("A5:AA26").getValues();
  
  //Get a lock on this script, because we're about to modify a shared resource
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  
  //Wait 30 seconds for other processes to finish
  lock.waitLock(30000);
  
  //Logger.log(data[0][2]); //- email address
  
  var email = data[0][2];
  var name = data[0][1];
  var subject = "DelQS - Estimated cash flow for your project";
  
  //Generate attachment
  
  hideSheetsforPrint();
  
  //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
   var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
  
      // Print either the entire Spreadsheet or the specified sheet if optSheetId is provided
      +  ('&id=' + sourceSpreadSheet())

      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'          // paper size
      + '&portrait=false'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&printnotes=false' // remove notes
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

   var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  }
  
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/" + url_ext, options);
   var blob = response.getBlob().setName('Estimated cash flow.pdf');
    
  showAllSheets();

  var projectName = data[0][3]; //project name (optional)
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("notificationCashFlowEmail");
  
  //set the values for placeholders in the html file
  htmlBody.name = name;
  
  //evaluate and get the html file
  var emailHtml = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent();
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, emailHtml, {htmlBody: emailHtml,attachments: [blob]});
  
  var d = new Date();
  
  //responseSheet.getRange(replied).setValue(d); //optional to below line
  responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow(),responseSheet.getLastColumn()).setValue(d);
  
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  //Release the lock so that other processes can continue
  lock.releaseLock();
 
}
```

Comment: Why not use the event object? It contains the specific response used to trigger the script.

Comment: As mentioned still very new. Could you possible give an example of how this would work?

Comment: Rule number one of learning: use documentation. There are two possible form submission triggers, depending where the trigger is (the Form or the destination Sheet). They have different event objects. Both are described here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Unfortunately documentation only helps if you understand it ;). I will do some more research on the event object

Comment: I'm still stuck. I have not managed to send an email to all parties submitting a form but the attachment that is generated by the script is the same for all parties ie the last conversion to pdf is sent to all respondents

Comment: Why are you reading from the sheet again? The Sheets version of the form submit event object includes the responses. And then you erroneously access a sheet with `getLastRow` despite having a more accurate row reference in the event object. Based on your description of the issue you have not properly implemented locking and flushing of content.

Comment: techhowch, you are correct. I have limited experience in coding and therefore my situation but managed to solve it by utilising the row of the submission based on the event. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: You can provide a self-answer to help others benefit from your solution, if you feel it may be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer